# Retweet twitter posts on website

Tags: html, css, twitter

I'm a newbie and want to create a website, that retweets posts from twitter of a certain hashtag automatically on my site. I want to use my own css style for the posts and embed the raw content to my website.

Is that possible?
What's the easiest language and way to solve this? Every 5 minutes the website should scan twitter again for new tags.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Hi Sol! This seems like a pretty simple idea. I'm sure you can get this done on any web programming language that has a Twitter API client!

Comment: so if I choose javascript for example , how can I than write an app that automatically embeds posts on my website?

Answer (score 0):

Basically [Twitter Api](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) seems to support everything that you need. You'll have to authenticate with OAuth, after that you can call the link of the API with the parameters (Like shown in [this](http://iag.me/socialmedia/build-your-first-twitter-app-using-php-in-8-easy-steps/) tutorial with php) and you'll get a JSON back, which means you can use any programming langauge that can parse JSON (so basically every web-language you like).

Here's a tutorial that might get close to what you want, but it's written in php: [code.tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-with-the-twitter-api-getting-started--cms-22192)